# What is a good annotation for the aggregation_function in pd.Series.agg(aggregation_function)?

Tags: python, pandas, python-typing

Simplified a lot, I have code like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def aggregate_series(series: pd.Series, agg_function: Callable) -> Any:
    return series.agg(agg_function)
```

I would like to annotate this better. What are the parameters of `agg_function`? The return type cannot be specified better than `Any`, right?

Examples for `agg_functions`:

- `sum`, `min`, `max` (the Python built-ins)
- `np.mean`, `np.median` (numpy functions)
- Anything custom: `lambda n: max(el for el in n if el < 2)`

Please note that `max` could also operate on a series of strings. And the custom function can, of course, operate on any type of object.

Is `agg_function: Callable[Sequence[Any], Any]` correct? Is it the best I can do?